# jquery hover not working after being moved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a "catch the button game" so I have to move a button and if I move it the hover event doesn't work anymore.
I tried it with normal js but that didnt help either.

Comment: btw i couldnt add code because stackoverwlof wont let me

Comment: What do you mean it won't let you? Without the code we can't help you.

Comment: it says too much code

Comment: Then reduce your problem to the minimum amount necessary to reproduce the problem you're facing. We don't need to read through your entire application's code to help you with a problem like the one you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

In the Case of the Dynamically added elements, It is better to add the event with the parent element. So you can use 'html' or 'body' tag for that.

> .on(events[,selector][,data],handler)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').on('hover', '.btnClass', function () {
        // do you work
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have a dynamic added element(button). Therefor you need to use the `.on` using jQuery. ✌️

```js
$(".buttonClass").on("hover", function () {
// your function.
});
```